# Why all the registered user are AnonymousUserMixin?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I'm creating my first login form but I don't know why every time I log in my app recognizes the user as an anonymous user
why when I log with an existing user it make the user anonymous ?

this my db create with sqlalchemy and integrated for flask-login

```
class User(db.Model):  # Creazione Tabella User
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    # colonne di user
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    surname = db.Column(db.String(80),  nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(256), unique=True, nullable=False)
    cell = db.Column(db.String(16))
    skill = db.Column(db.String(256))
    office = db.Column(db.String(32))
    role = db.Column(db.String(32))
    pwd_hash = db.Column(db.String(200))
    base64 = db.Column(db.String(256))
    makePermision = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=0)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=0)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)


    # Funzioni per accedere ai dati di user

    def get_id(self):  
        return self.email

    def get_email(self):
        return self.email


    def get_pwd_hash(self):
        return self.pwd_hash

    def get_active(self):
        return self.get_active

    def is_active(self):  # richiesta obbligatoriamente da Flask-login
        return True

    def is_authenticated(self):  # richiesta obbligatoriamente da Flask-login
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):  # richiesta obbligatoriamente da Flask-login
        return False
```

this how I insert data in the DB to register a new user

```
 new_user = User(
                    name=form.name.data,
                    surname=form.surname.data,
                    email=form.email.data.lower(),
                    cell=str(form.cell.data),
                    skill=form.skill.data,
                    office=form.office.data,
                    role=form.role.data,
                    pwd_hash=form.password.data,  # TODO: QUI BISOGNA PRIMA FARE L'HASH
                    base64="Not implemented",
                    active=False,
                    makePermision=False
                )
                db.session.add(new_user)  # inserico l'oggetto nel DB
                db.session.commit()

                flash("Utente registrato, l'admin è stato allertato, aspetta l'abilitazione")

                return redirect(url_for('signin'))
```

and this is how make the login bur every time it's  gives me an anonymous user

```
    elif request.method == 'POST':  # con POST
        if form.validate_on_submit():  # se i dati pasano la validazione
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data.lower()).first()

            if user:
                if user.pwd_hash == form.password.data:
                    print("STEP 1")
                    email = user.email
                    print("STEP 2")
                    login_user(user)

                    return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))
                else:
                    flash("Password o email errata")
                    return render_template("signin.html", form=form)
            # qui si può specificare che l'email è sbagliata

    return render_template("signin.html", form=form)
```

Comment: Look at how [UserMixin](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_login/mixins.html#UserMixin) is defined. Should your `is_***` instance methods be properties?

Comment: What changes by inserting @property?